# Making paragraphs for the outline using comments in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, code-organization

Is it possible to use comments to organise the code in paragraphs that could be available in the outline.

This would be helpful for organizing classes with a lot of methods.

I would be in particular interested in doing that inside python classes.

Example:

```
class Class():
# Special comment to be in the outline: First methods
def a(self):
    pass
def b(self):
    pass
def c(self):
    pass
# Special comment to be in the outline: Other methods
def d(self):
    pass
def e(self):
    pass
```

[image: Outline should group the function according to the special comment]
Outline should group the function according to the special comment

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

vscode supports `#regions` for python, which makes it possible to collapse & expand the regions using the outline markers in the gutter.  These regions don't appear in the Outline in the sidebar.  There have been discussions in the [vscode issues for outlines](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aopen%20label%3Afeature-request%20label%3Aoutline) but it doesn't seem to be in any danger of being implemented any time soon.

Here's the #region example

```
class Class():
    #region Special comment to be in the outline: First methods
    def a(self):
        pass
    def b(self):
        pass
    def c(self):
        pass
    #endregion
    #region Special comment to be in the outline: Other methods
    def d(self):
        pass
    def e(self):
        pass
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any direct solution for this, but you can use some extensions like **MARKS** https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=roabramov.marks-to-outline or **Better Outlines** https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adamerose.better-outline or **Outline Map** https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gerrnperl.outline-map
With all of those extensions you can add # region and show it in you outline view, sometime you should edit regex like in MARKS, but other show region fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct solution to your request, but this extension takes comment anchors and shows then in a list, so similar use-case:
[Comment anchors](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ExodiusStudios.comment-anchors)